# оптимизация mysql запроса с подзапросом

Tags: mysql

С помощью профайлера, нашел запрос, который дольше всех выполняется, мною были проставлены индексы, но на время исполнения данного запроса это не повлияло, как можно его оптимизировать? Вроде конструкции `HAVING` ресурсозатратная, как пишут в сети.

```
 SELECT e.id, 
           e.tid 
    FROM   entries e
    WHERE  e.pid = 0  AND spam = 0 
           AND e.category IN (0, 1)
           AND (e.user_id NOT IN ("") 
               OR e.id IN (SELECT tid 
                             FROM entries 
                            WHERE tid = e.id 
                              AND user_id NOT IN ("") 
                           HAVING COUNT(*) > 1))
    ORDER  BY e.sticky DESC, 
              time DESC
    LIMIT  0, 30
```

данные перечисляемые в `NOT IN ("")` одинаковые

Comment: было бы легче, если были данные как пример. типо что есть что нужно

Comment: @Mike, tid=e.id - unknown column in where clause, как исправить? вроде, ваш пример пошустрее:  SELECT e.id, 
           e.tid 
    FROM   entries e
    WHERE  e.pid = 0  AND spam = 0 
           AND e.category IN (0, 1)
           AND (e.user_id NOT IN ("") 
               OR (select count(1) from (select 1 from entries where tid=e.id and user_id not in("") limit 2) A)>1)
    ORDER  BY e.sticky DESC, 
              time DESC
    LIMIT  0, 30

Comment: @Mike, а если более одного?

Comment: @Mike спасибо, ваше ответы всегда выручают! Видимо сильно закешерировалось, после прочтения ответа еще раз проверил все ок!

Comment: @Mike было 0.250sec, стало 0,100sec, экономия на спичках, но в совокупности все стало быстрее грузиться

Comment: @aliokero Перенес в ответ. Ну так в 2.5 раза :) хотя на таких маленьких цифрах не показатель. вообще запрос тяжелым выглядит и при росте базы может еще проблемы вызвать. тут на днях у себя в системе нашел статистический запрос, запускавшийся раз в 5 минут и ради подсчета кол-ва накопленного за эти 5 минут делавшем полное сканирование таблицы, в коей накопилось 7 млн записей  ... А лишние коменты трем, Волынкин ругается и он прав, слишком много воды :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT e.id, 
       e.tid 
FROM   entries e
WHERE  e.pid = 0  AND spam = 0 
       AND e.category IN (0, 1)
       AND (e.user_id NOT IN ("") 
            OR EXISTS(SELECT 1
                        FROM entries 
                       WHERE tid = e.id AND user_id NOT IN ("") 
                       limit 1,1
                    )
           )
ORDER  BY e.sticky DESC, 
          time DESC
LIMIT  0, 30
```

limit 1,1 в подзапросе вернет только 2-ю строку и exists сработает аналогично count()>1.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
SELECT e.id, 
       e.tid 
  FROM entries e
 INNER JOIN (SELECT tid, COUNT(*) cou
               FROM entries 
              WHERE user_id NOT IN ("")
              GROUP BY tid) j ON tid = e.id AND cou > 1
 WHERE e.pid = 0 
   AND spam = 0 
   AND e.category IN (0, 1)
ORDER  BY e.sticky DESC, 
          time DESC
LIMIT  0, 30
```

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению, Ваш пример в 3 раза дольше отрабатывает(

Comment: @aliokero может вам поможет `LEFT JOIN` вместо `INNER JOIN`?